# How to set the dynamically created items to the Listbox as selected via composer

Tags: zk

I'm creating the new record via composer and want to set the same as selected in the existing listbox without afecting the existing selection of the listbox in zul page.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: get the selected obj in the listbox and clone it and pass it to the creation form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have kept the params in session and received it in composer and added to newly created list

ListModelList listModel = new ListModelList<>();

and set the above list default selected as

listModel.setSelection(listModel);

added remain items as

```
listModel.addAll(remainItemsList);
combobox.setModel(listModel);
```